# how to set one linear layout below another linear layout in android

Tags: android

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation=""
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/imagecontainlayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".75"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Status:"
                    android:textColor="#0060a4"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3.5"
                    android:textColor="#0060a4"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="20dip"
                    android:layout_height="20dip"
                    android:layout_weight=".75" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="295dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Status:"
                android:textColor="#0060a4"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3.5"
                android:textColor="#0060a4"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Xml am trying to set imagecontainlayout linear layout  to another linear layout containing another linear layout with some gap but i dont know where am doing mistake in my code my current screen is coming like this .[image]

my current screen is coming like this while i want there first layout below another  layout with some gap please help me where am doing mistake.

Comment: android:orientation="" give it a value "vertical" remove the unwanted closing </LinearLayout> tag

Comment: well, why did you assign weight=5, width=0 for the 1st nested LinearLayout while the 2nd nested does not have weight and width=295dp, i think if you want them to be fit-aligned you need to set same params for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Step:"
                android:textColor="#0060a4"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/step"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3.5"
                android:textColor="#0060a4"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

use this code it will Help u .